Bitcoin core having trouble connecting to peers
New to Bitcoin.
I have been trying to host a full node on my Mac. I just installed bitcoin core but while syncing, it seems my node is unable to connect to any peers. I am regularly checking the debug.log file and it has been giving a "Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer"  regularly about every 10 minutes and this has been going on for 3-4 hours. I checked online and it says there are some firewall issues and maybe my internet connection isn't allowing me to connect to port 8333. I checked my firewall settings and I am not blocking any ports from my end. Here is my debug.log file:
2024-04-04T03:46:06Z Waiting 300 seconds before querying DNS seeds.
2024-04-04T03:55:17Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sipa.be.
2024-04-04T03:55:20Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoinstats.com.
2024-04-04T03:55:20Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.wiz.biz.
2024-04-04T03:55:21Z Waiting 300 seconds before querying DNS seeds.
2024-04-04T03:56:02Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2651 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T04:14:37Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 3766 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T04:14:37Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2024-04-04T04:30:22Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 4711 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T04:46:42Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 5691 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T05:02:42Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 6651 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T05:03:02Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org.
2024-04-04T05:03:02Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.btc.petertodd.org.
2024-04-04T05:03:03Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl.
2024-04-04T05:03:03Z 204 addresses found from DNS seeds
2024-04-04T05:03:03Z dnsseed thread exit
2024-04-04T05:20:04Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 7693 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T05:20:04Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2024-04-04T05:37:15Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 8724 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T05:56:46Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 9895 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T06:14:17Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 10946 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T06:31:39Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 11988 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T06:31:39Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2024-04-04T06:48:50Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 13019 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T07:00:05Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 13694 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T07:14:56Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 14585 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T07:25:26Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 15215 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T07:31:39Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat.
2024-04-04T07:37:48Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 15957 seconds ago)
2024-04-04T07:48:18Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 16587 seconds ago)

This goes on forever.
I have an M1 chip and macOS 14.4.1

wondering if you found a solution here. I don't have this particular issue but on my node running on a Mac (m1 mini) I occasionally see long periods of "connecting to peers". And in general initializing my node is taking a very long time. I'm 4 weeks in and still only at 72%! I'm also on macOS 14.4.1

@neils4fun If you run bitcoin-cli getchaintips, do you see "invalid" anywhere in the output?
